# Using OAuth 2.0 for Devices :Some requested scopes were invalid

Tags: android

After you have the client ID and client secret, you send an HTTP POST to the OAuth 2.0 device endpoint at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code with your client_id and a list of scopes. Unlike the other OAuth 2.0 flows, response_type and redirect_uri are not needed in the device flow. The following is an example request for a user code:

POST /o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com&
scope=email%20profile

I have tried but it results all time:

{
  "error" : "invalid_scope",
  "error_description" : "Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[rad365rad@gmail.com]}",
  "error_uri" : "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"
}

can anyone solve this..where i am wrong please

Comment: i have made post request to the above mentioned url but same response is getting please can one help me to get output like:                                                                                                          {
  "device_code" : "4/4-GMMhmHCXhWEzkobqIHGG_EnNYYsAkukHspeYUk9E8",
  "user_code" : "GQVQ-JKEC",
  "verification_url" : "https://www.google.com/device",
  "expires_in" : 1800,
  "interval" : 5
}

Answer (score 1):

You can start from here, this should help get you the device code

curl -d "client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email profile" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code